# BackboneJS - cacheing view instances

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, backbone.js

I'm writing a BackboneJS app where each of six tabs are represented by their own views. Am I supposed to save the instance of the view and just call it's `render()` function whenever a user hits a tab he's already been to? Or create a new instance and access the template that jQuery cached for me during the first rendering?

If I do the latter, I would still need to make sure another collection isn't fetched through my JSON API, since that's done during initialization of some views.

Right now I store all view instances in my controller but I was wondering if this was built-in somehow or there are better alternatives.

Cheers.

Update: Here's my `loadCachedView` function that I use in my controller:

```
loadCachedView: function (name, view, collection){
    if (!this.views[name]){
        if (collection){
            this.collections[name] = new collection();
        }
        this.views[name] = new view({collection: this.collections[name]});
    } else {
        this.views[name].render();
    }
},
```

So when rendering a view, I just go: `this.loadCachedView('settings', SettingsView, SettingsCollcetion)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I usually keep track of all my views in my controller. The controller then switch between available views based on the nav events:

```
var Switches;
Switches = [];
Skepic.SwitchView = Backbone.View.extend({
    hide: function() {
        return this.el.detach();
    },
    show: function() {
        if (!_.include(Switches, this)) {
            Switches.push(this);
        }
        _.each(Switches, function(s) {
            return s.hide();
        });
        this.container().append(this.el);
        return $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: 0
        }, 'fast', "linear");
    },
    container: function() {
        if (this.options.container) {
            return this.options.container;
        } else {
            return $("body > .content");
        }
    }
});
```

This is kind of the base view to switch between one view and the other. The controller will create the view (fetching data as needed) and when you switch, you can do your last checks in an overriden show() function in the view.

(notice I use detach on the jQuery to still have the event delegation working)

Comment: I needed to change this.el.detach() to $(this.el).detach() for the code to work. Otherwise I had a similar requirement and this is the best solution I've come across.

Comment: So that does mean you do the same as I did, with the loadCachedView, or similar (saving the view's instance and just calling it's show() function)?

Comment: I guess yes. But it is removed from the dom not hidden.

Comment: Could you paste your controller, too? In order for the `show()` to work, you'd need to cache the instance separately from this, right? And then re-use that instance and call it's `show` function.

Comment: This is not caching, this is referencing an object and yes you need to keep a reference to it to show/hide it.

Answer (score 1):

Couldn't you make use of the .memoize function here?

Comment: @Jonatan `_.memoize` it's an in build caching function with underscore.

Comment: Ah, I only looked in Backbone's docs. Plus I thought he misspelt 'memorize' :-)

Comment: I guess it could work with _.memoize too .. the idea is to keep your tab contents in memory and not reload them if not necessary ... And it made me discover this cool function :)

Comment: i'm a she, and also, it's not memorize - i thought this for a long time, too. It appears constantly throughout many js libraries so I can only figure that it was a badly formed l33t speak paradigm that has now run amok. Memoize should help you.

Comment: memoize is not to be confused with memorize :) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization